# Same select criteria with multiple where conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to do something like this when there are same fields required from the table but having different where conditions.

I have tried to do it like this but there is something missing in it that's why its not working properly.

```
;WITH ProductsCTE (PSC_Score_0_11, PSC_Score_12_18, PSC_Score_19_23,
                   PSC_Score_24_34, PSC_Score_35_50, PSC_Score_51_100,
                   Total AS
( 
    SELECT
        SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_0_11)) AS PSC_Score_0_11,
        SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_12_18)) AS PSC_Score_12_18,
        SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_19_23)) AS PSC_Score_19_23,
        SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_24_34)) AS PSC_Score_24_34,
        SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_35_50)) AS PSC_Score_35_50,
        SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_51_100)) AS PSC_Score_51_100,
        (SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_0_11)) + SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_12_18)) + 
         SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_19_23)) + SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_24_34)) + 
         SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_35_50)) + SUM(CONVERT(int, PSC_Score_51_100))) AS Total
    FROM
        VillageLevelPscData
)
SELECT * 
FROM ProductsCTE
WHERE [DISTRICT_NAME] = 'ABC'

UNION ALL 

SELECT * 
FROM ProductsCTE
WHERE [DISTRICT_NAME] = 'DEF'
```

I want to get the result as sum of "PSC_Score_0_11" and others where district = 'ABC' and district = 'DEF' and union all them into one table.

I get an error for this query:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

I want to get the results like this for each individual district.

[image]

Comment: what is wrong with your code? does it not compile? > error? does it not deliver the expected results > what do you expect? For the case you show, you can just as well write `WHERE [DISTRICT_NAME] IN ('ABC','DEF')`, or when you need aggregates per query, use a view. I don't see how this would benefit from a common table expression.

Comment: [DISTRICT_NAME] is not in ProductsCTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want:

```
select district_name,
       sum(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_0_11 )) as PSC_Score_0_11,
       sum(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_12_18 )) as PSC_Score_12_18,
       sum(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_19_23 )) as PSC_Score_19_23,
       sum(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_24_34 )) as PSC_Score_24_34,
       sum(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_35_50 )) as PSC_Score_35_50,
       sum(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_51_100 )) as PSC_Score_51_100,
       (SUM(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_0_11 )) + SUM(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_12_18 )) + 
SUM(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_19_23 )) + SUM(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_24_34 ))
 + SUM(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_35_50 ))+ SUM(CONVERT(int,PSC_Score_51_100 ))
       ) as Total
from VillageLevelPscData
group by district_name;
```

The CTE doesn't seem particularly useful.